# My website using Docker cannot be reached by our company members in India (from American)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

Here is my docker-compose file (with a few details taken out for privacy). The problem is that the site is available for everyone on our work network here, but those in other countries in other networks cannot. How can I resolve this so that everyone in the company can see the site?

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: ###
    volumes:
     - ###
    networks:
     - my-network

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: ###
    volumes:
     - ###
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      DB_HOST: database
    networks:
     - my-network

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: ###
    networks:
     - my-network

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: ###
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
     - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    ipam:
      config:
       - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: are you accessing a website by using IP address? can you tell us what URL you are using for a website?

Comment: No, I'm using a domain. I can't say the actually site, but it's like mysite.example.com. But you can't access mysite from any other network in town, just at work. I guess my question should be, how do I add access to the networks my fellow coworkers are using?

Comment: I feel like they're being blocked out just like I am from my home network, but I'd like to add special access for those in India but I'm not sure of the commands I need and what I need from India

Comment: https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime try this service to check from where is site available

Comment: Have you configured (mysite.example.com) domain name to use your Docker machine Ip address and port number (where the application is running)? you domain name needs to point to your machine IP address and port number (it needs to be configured in NGINX server) or you have to export port number to the outside world to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had too many old network bridges open and one of them was the IP address my coworkers were on and it was blocking them.
So to fix it, I did

```
> ip addr
> docker network ls
```

And then you could prune if you see that there's too many open

```
> docker network prune
```